# Nginx writing logs to wrong file

Tags: php, symfony, logging, nginx

I am using nginx for my production and development environment.

I have configured vhosts correctly with each virtual hosts writing log to separate file.

But in my case I am seeing few lines in production logs showing development environment error data.

I have rechecked config, everything looks fine.

Is this a known bug from nginx.

**Edit**

*root@web01:/var/www/production# tail -n -20 /var/log/nginx/production-mobile-error.log*

```
[06-Jan-2014 10:42:37 UTC] PHP Notice: Undefined variable: duplicateProductId in /var/www/production-srikanth-dev/Controller.php on line 619
```

*root@web01:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# grep -ri 'production-mobile-error' **

```
default.production-mobile: error_log /var/log/nginx/production-mobile-error.log error;
default.production-mobile: error_log /var/log/nginx/production-mobile-error.log error;
```

Comment: Okay, glad to hear you checked your config. Can you show this to us? Which files are being written, and which ones do you expect them to be?

Comment: Can you please post a snap of your nginx.conf file and your virtual.conf file?

Comment: @user151277: please put the content of your configuration file in the question by editing it.

Comment: Are you sure you are seeing the latest log entries and not the ones before the reconfiguration? Also have you restarted the webserver?